# Making a request back to the same machine results in 403

Tags: asp.net

I have an "It works on my machine" issue.

When I execute the following on my machine it works fine but on my integration server I'm handed a 403 forbidden response.

```
var cookie = page.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
var authenticationCookie = new Cookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, page.Request.Url.Authority);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(appRoot + item.Path);
request.UserAgent = page.Request.UserAgent;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(authenticationCookie);

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Any thoughts on what I may be missing? I can take the request address and paste in my browser and it comes up fine. Maybe I'm missing some headers? The integration server is running on a self-signed cert (https).

Comment: any proxies and/or proxy authentication?

Comment: @Rubens I bet that's it... I'll have to hunt down tech support which seems to be hiding at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a proxy server thing, it wasn't allowing the server to make requests back to itself.

This required some tech support mojo.